# How to enable copy paste in google chrome if it is been disabled by website?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, copy-paste

Did lot of research work but don't know how to do this.
Help me guys.

Comment: Since the software recommendations are off-topic here,  I have posted a similar question on the software recommendation SE website http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/37322/903

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Where is it implied by the question that it is about a software recommendation? The normal answer to expect here is a chrome setting or some code snippet that would disable a custom javascript event handler.

Comment: @JannisIoannou It's not implied. I agree with you. Sorry my previous comment was poorly phrased. I meant that I asked a software recommendation question ([Google Chrome extension that can allow copying text](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/37322/903)) that is very similar to this question (but not the same). IMHO this question should've been migrated to SU, not closed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this add on?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-copy/abidndjnodakeaicodfpgcnlkpppapah?hl=en-US

That or looking at the source of the page (depending on the method they block it with) or inspecting elements. It's all on your computer, you just need to disable some scripts to make them more manageable.

Comment: @Rustyalready tried,not working.And disabling the script is not an good idea because now days almost every website uses script for there designing and display,and if i disable the script  it will be for every website.I am just finding another way that i can control copy or paste .